# Allow multiple IPs with the Require directive in Apache 2.4

Tags: apache-2.4

I am migrating from Apache 2.2 to 2.4, and would like to prefer the use of "Require" than the now discouraged use of `Allow`, `Deny`.

My question: How can I allow access from a set of IP addresses or ranges, by having one address/range per line in the configuration file?

With Apache 2.2, I used:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from 2001:1000:2000::1/64
Allow from 1.2.3.4
Allow from 1.2.3.10
```

How would that translate to the new access control syntax?

Comment: I believe you want [RequireAny](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html#requireany) together with [Require](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html#host) directives.

Answer (score 23):

The *upgrading* documentation has clear information on how to do this. It is also something that should be read in case any other configuration changes are required: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html

Also you do not need to put different IP addresses or networks on separate lines. It is perfectly acceptable to do the following:

```
# Apache v2.2
Allow from 1.2.3.4 1.2.3.10
# Apache v2.4
Require ip 1.2.3.4 1.2.3.10
```

Finally, the default is for multiple require directives to be treated as if they are in a `<RequireAny>` block, so unless you are forming a more complex nested grouping you do not need to add it. Though you may wish to for clarify of course. Reference: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/auth.html#beyond

Additional Information: One other thought is that when upgrading you should definitely go through all your configuration (including any `htaccess` files you might have) and convert the older Apache v2.2 directives to the Apache v2.4 ones, and then comment out the loading of the `mod_access_compat` module. Mixing v2.2 and v.24 directives can cause some very unusual problems that are hard to troubleshoot.

Comment: "Mixing v2.2 and v.24 directives can cause some very unusual problems that are hard to troubleshoot." +1

Comment: `Require ip 1.2.3.4 1.2.3.10` not working. Works is I put only one IP in there. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I know it is an old post but i think that can help with a functional example that i always use!

In apache 2.2 would be like:

```
    <Location />
       Order deny, allow
       allow from all
    </Location>
    <Location /adm>
        Order deny, allow
        deny from all
        allow from myniceip
    </Location>
    <Location /disabled>
        Order deny, allow
        deny from all
    </Location>
```

In apache 2.4 would be like:

```
   <Location />
       require all granted
    </Location>
   #Note that you dont need to use require all denied
   #to require only a group of ips.. 
    <Location /adm>
        require myniceip
    </Location>
    <Location /disabled>
        Require all denied
    </Location>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is to manage a list of specific IP addresses. For them, you just have to write:

```
Require ip 127.0.0.1
Require ip 127.0.0.2
```

For each line with the IP that you want to grant access.
Change the IP to which you want to offer access.
You can use [CIDR notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing).